# Improving speed on Android Emulator

Tags: android, performance, emulation, ram

Hello I am running a W510 Lenovo Laptop which is generally rapid in most computing circumstances but when running Eclipse and trying to run the AVD emulator it is like molasses.  I know that there are some alternative emulators and that I can improve the RAM on the emulator but what other ways can I speed it up.

I am thinking of upgrading from 4GB of RAM on my Lenovo to 12GB would this make a big difference?

Thanks

Comment: Aren't those two separate questions? I mean upgrading the tablet and the emulator?

Comment: Refer to Mark's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2662854/450534

Comment: What ADT version and emulator are you running? With the release of r17 earlier this month, Google the emulator has supposedly been sped up significantly, as mentioned in this [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html) on the dev blog, thanks to GPU acceleration and native access to the host CPU. I haven't actually been playing around with this myself yet, but it sounds definitely worth looking into.

Comment: yes two different questions but with the same goal.  I am running on the newest version and it starts up quickly but takes 5-7 minutes for my actual program to run.  Is there anyway the GPU acceleration could be turned off be default and if so how would I turn it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this may work for others:
I've faced the same problem with my high config pc have `3i 4GB` , but the emulator works so slow 
I found something that worked for me and hope it may work for others i would love to share it here

i've just added `Device ram size` to My existing `AVD` and set the `size to 1000MB`(Because i've enough to allot mine is 6GB)
No the speed of my `AVD` was ultimate hope it may help you.

**EDIT 1:**

You may also set some attribute for better performance like
set GPU Emulation = yes

[image: GPU Emulation Settings]

Answer (score 3):

If you have a dedicated GPU, try turning GPU acceleration on to significantly boost graphics performance. It is turned off by default. To turn it on, edit the AVD you use, and on the hardware section, click "New". Find "GPU emulation", add it, and set the value to yes.

Assuming that you only run eclipse, the emulator, and a bunch of Chrome tabs (no other RAM hungry processes going on), 4GB should be enough. My setup also has 4GB RAM with no swap space and if you check system monitor, most likely you still have spare free RAM. I personally still have 800 MB of free RAM when all of those things are open (with device ram size set to 512 MB).